# Icons for username and password

Tags: icons, login

I have login page with two input boxes, one for username and one for password. On the left of these input boxes, I want to put descriptive icons.

I think the profile of a bust, and a key, would be appropriate icons for username and password respectively. What do you think?

Also, how do I find such icons? I need both icons to match in style, and to be distributed a license which allows commercial reuse.

Comment: Are there any text labels as well?

Comment: Yeah, there are placeholder labels that disappear upon focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bust and a lock are some of the most used icons for this purpose... Here's an example from [LinguaLift](http://lingualift.com/):

[image]

Obviously, it is ideal to design your own icons or hire someone to design them for you, but there is also a great number of free icons collections which can be used with appropriate attribution.

The most famous and commonly used icon-set is [Silk](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) by FAMFAMFAM, but there's also 
the [Tango project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) and a number of others which you can find using the [Iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Your icons are what is usually used in this context (a password is also often represented with a lock), but you should only use them in addition to labels, they can't replace the labels altogether.

To find them, you can use websites such as [iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com), where you can filter results by license. A bunch of similar resources are reviewed [here](http://designm.ag/resources/find-icons/).

Answer (score 2):

Do icons make it clearer to your users than using text labels?  If not, I would suggest going for what is more usable rather than for what looks better.